# Show hide info.event.extendedProps.description Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to make `info.event.extendedProps.description` field show hide when I click event title in Fullcalendar list view. But it only works partly.

[Example here](https://codepen.io/Bo-Kj-rgaard/pen/vYrOJjq).

I added this under eventDidMount and works for line 1,3,5,7 etc. But not 2,4,6,8 etc

```js
//Initially hide all the item-content
$('.item-content').hide();

// Attach a click event to item-title
$('.item-title').on('click', function() {
  //Find the next element having class item-content
  $(this).next('.item-content').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `off()`, off() method removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`, so its works.

In your case:

```
$('.item-title').off().on('click', function () {
    //Find the next element having class item-content
    $(this).next('.item-content').toggle();
});
```

*Note: I tested your code with `off()` on your codepen and it's work.*